# siunitx: the detect-all option puts \celsius in math mode?

Tags: siunitx

Something is wrong with the Celsius unit and the `detect-all` option (see below).

[image]

I finally removed the `detect-all` option to fix the problem, but still, there may be some bug here.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\chapter{What is happening here?}

Good: \SI{50}{\celsius}, \SI{30}{\watt\per\meter}.\\
\sisetup{detect-all}
But after \verb=\sisetup{detect-all}=, the celsius unit (and only this one) is in math mode: \SI{50}{\celsius}, \SI{30}{\watt\per\meter}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I think I know what's going on here: trying to satisfy all requirements is hard!

Comment: I'm pretty sure my system is up-to-date (TeXlive, regularly updated) and use I pdfLaTeX. @JosephWright: please note that I do not require anything, just pointing out some odd behavior ^^.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 14.04, and the pretty old TeXLive (2012 I think) that comes with it, and the second °C comes out exactly as the first one.

Comment: Bibi, no worries, Joseph did not say that *you* are asking for something special. I guess he was just a bit resigned as he was introducing [some fix](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/commit/d38cdf4bcc5e32d1a525a0f5ee32990fe95b3481) for [some other issue](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/282) just two weeks ago. As you are having the most recent TL-version, it seems as if you have found some more work for him... We'll see.

Comment: It's math mode not italicized by the way.

Comment: @percusse: you are right. Question edited.

Comment: It is on MiKTeX now. It was me having an outdated system.

Comment: I'll need to think a bit to find a solution that works for all of the issues: may take a day or so.

Comment: No worries! (And thanks for the awesome package!)

Comment: @JosephWright: I just noticed the problem is gone! Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a problem with has been fixed in the meantime.